# Concerete stats on how not-FIFO is Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

has anyone tried to run tests and see how often SQS returns messages out of FIFO order? Please ignore this question if you have never pondered on the same topic or do not have interest in it. Do not just merely vote this down if you simply think it is not important to me, it may be to some. I am in the process of making a pro or con SQS decision and need help from other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Amazon SQS is distributed across lots of machines. So, even if it was FIFO out of a single machine, it doesn't mean that you'd hit the same machine in the cluster over and over until all messages were received.

AWS makes it explicitly clear that you cannot rely on FIFO in SQS.

That said, using the SDKs or CLI, it's be pretty easy to put 10,000 messages in with a value from 1-10,000, then pull those messages back out and compare.

There is also documentation that states that if you have fewer than 1,000 messages in SQS, you're not even guaranteed to receive a message when you request one, so you need to handle the exception gracefully and try again.

The enforcement of FIFO needs to happen at the application-level. For example, if you have received message #4567, and you want message #4568, you'll need to fetch, compare, and release-without-deleting until it comes up. This will be slow and resource-intensive, and is not a recommended approach when working with distributed message queues.